# What kind of data exposed from linkedin API

Tags: api, linkedin-api

Wanted to know what kind of info is exposed with linked-in api?.  Particularly I want to know how may levels of connection info it exposes (I mean first, second ...etc)?. Are there any ready made test tools or web page which does this (to see what data being exposed)?

Answer (score 2):

Whatever level of information the user has specified for show.
But in most cases, it will be name, location, job title, company, past companies, education. You can also drill in to information such as your contacts.

I would checkout https://developer.linkedin.com/

Answer (score 0):

you can get 1st and 2nd degree network (connections)

Comment: From question: "Particularly I want to know how may levels of connection info it exposes (i mean first, second ...etc)?." My answer: 1st and 2nd. How this is not answering the questions?